# Социально-адаптивный или социально адаптивный?

Tags: слитно-раздельно-дефис

Социально-адаптивный или социально адаптивный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: ***социально-адаптивный.***

**АДАПТАЦИЯ,** ж. [от лат. adaptāre - приспосабливать]. Спец. 1. Процесс привыкания, приспособления органов чувств и организма в целом к новым, изменившимся условиям существования. 2. Приспособление (упрощение) текста для начинающих изучать иностранные языки, для детского чтения. <Адаптационный, -ая, -ое (1 зн.). А-ая способность глаза. А. период аквалангистов.

**АДАПТИРОВАТЬ**,  св. и нсв. Произвести - производить адаптацию (2 зн.). А. текст.

Существует термин: **Социально-адаптивный тип личности.** Например, социально-адаптивный тип личности преступника отличается высоким уровнем нервно-психической, эмоционально-волевой устойчивости, сопротивляемостью (толерантностью) к стрессу ... Термин пишется через дефис. Он обозначает **внутренние свойства** нервной системы.

Для сравнения. **Раздельно** пишутся сочетания с причастными формами, например: социально ориентированный, социально адаптированный. Здесь личностные качества человек получает в результате направленного внешнего воздействия (воспитания).